# Where to save private files when using UIFileSharingEnabled

Tags: ios

`UIFileSharingEnabled` set to yes makes the documents directory accessible to the user.

Where should one store files and folders outside of the documents directory that are private to the app and should not be visible to the user in the iTunes file sharing window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These go into `~/Library`. For details on the various subdirectories, see [The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) in the File System Programming Guide. Generally your files will go in `~/Library/Application Support`.

Comment: You can use `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` to access the `Library/Application Support` folder. Keep in mind that this folder does not existing in iOS by default. You will need to create it first.

Comment: Excellent note @rmaddy. For details on how to do that, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html

Comment: Is this path private, or can multiple applications read from this folder?

Comment: Each app has its own ~/Library. In order to share files between applications, you need to use the Document Provider app extension system: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html  This doesn't allow apps to read arbitrary files from other apps.